# Flutter GoogleMap widget cloudMapId property not working in emulator

Tags: flutter, google-maps, plugins

[google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter/changelog): ^2.5.0 plugin implements cloudMapId for custom map styling before download, I've set it all up in the app console with a retro style, plugged it in, and the emulator just loads a normal map, no styling. Am I doing something wrong?

```
GoogleMap(
        key: Key("myGoogleMap"),
        // map retro styling:
        cloudMapId: kIsWeb ? "761aa5d259aeabXX" : "be3206753e9be6XX",
```

I have it working by string in the dart file, but it applies the style too late on the web, you get the conventional map style flashing before the custom style is applied.

Comment: did you try it on the real device?

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that you might have missed (I did too):

## Android

Cloud-based Map styling is supported only with the latest renderer. This is documented [here](https://github.com/flutter/packages/tree/main/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter#cloud-based-map-styling).

Here is how to set the renderer: [README: google_maps_flutter_android](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter_android#map-renderer). (You will need to add this package to your `pubspec.yaml` to use the api - it is used under the hood by `google_maps_flutter`)

## iOS

<s>Cloud-based Map styling is supported starting GoogleMaps iOS SDK version 8.3.1. Since *my* flutter project had minimum deployment target set to 11.0, CocoaPods installed GoogleMaps 5.X.X instead of 8.3.1 (or higher).</s>

This is not documented well. I found [this merge request](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/6553) where people are discussing the requirement to increase min sdk level to 12.

For me it started installing the correct GoogleMaps version when I increased minimum deployment target to 14.0. This is also documented in the [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/release-notes#May_17_2023) of the iOS Google Maps SDK 8.0.

After reinstalling the plugin and your Pods make sure, that your `Podfile.lock` contains `GoogleMaps (8.3.1)` (or higher).

**Update:** I created a [merge request](https://github.com/flutter/packages/pull/5844) with a hint to that in the Flutter packages repository. With the help of one of the collaborators I found out that what I wrote is not exactly true.

While this was solving my problem (and might solve your problem too) the issue is not simply about the feature being being unsupported in earlier sdk versions.

Indeed I set up a fresh flutter sample app (minimum: iOS 12.0), added the library, added a `cloudMapId` and it worked out of the box (with google maps sdk version 5.X).